# Image resize on window resize?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use object-fit but it doesn't seem to be very compatible with new browsers etc. - I just want it to cover the space not get squashed when resized, is there a way in css or jquery that just covers the space rather than gets resized and squashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with using a background image on another element instead of an image-tag, then you can use [background-size: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images) like this:

```
#myDiv{
    background-image:url(/path/to/bg/image); 
    background-size: cover
}
```

Comment: No i cannot remove img tags as I'm getting everything from a database.. :(

Answer (score 0):

use the viewport width and height properties after setting the viewport to device-width, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And your css:

```
width:100vw; height:100vh; /*this is like a percentage of the viewport width and height*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery,

```
    $(function () {

        var theWindow = $(window),
            $bg = $("#bg"),
            aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

        function resizeBg() {

            if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio) {
                $bg.removeClass()
                    .addClass('bgheight');
            } else {
                $bg.removeClass()
                    .addClass('bgwidth');
            }

        }

        theWindow.resize(function () {
            resizeBg();
        }).trigger("resize");

    });
```

See [***demo here***](http://jsfiddle.net/hB2nY/)